# Make a .click override .on('mouseover')

Tags: jquery, html

Im making a timeline, and it shows info when being hovered over, but I also want it to be clickable, and when clicked, stay visible until another button is clicked, or the button is clicked again. How do I do this?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s4yvbqzL/2/)

My html:

```
<div class="timeline-pills">
        <div class='timeline-element' id='year-1492'>
            <p>1492</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-element' id='year-1607'>
            <p>1607</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-element' id='year-1620'>
            <p>1620</p>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-info-panels">
            <div class='timeline-info' id='1492'>
            <p>1492</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-info' id='1607'>
            <p>1607</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-info' id='1620'>
            <p>1620</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('.timeline-element').on('mouseenter', function(){
$(this).addClass('hover-over-time-pill')
$('.timeline-info-panels').show();

var hoverID = $(this).attr("id");
var newID = hoverID.replace('year-', '');
$('#'+newID).show();
});

$('.timeline-element').on('mouseleave', function(){
$(this).removeClass('hover-over-time-pill')
$('.timeline-info-panels').hide();

var hoverID = $(this).attr("id");
var newID = hoverID.replace('year-', '');
$('#'+newID).hide();    
});

$('.timeline-element').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('timeline-click');
    $('.timeline-info-panels').show();

    var clickID = $(this).id;
    var newID = clickID.substring(0,5);
    $('#'+newID).show();
});
$('.timeline-element').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('timeline-click');
    $('.timeline-info-panels').hide();

    var clickID = $(this).id;
    var newID = clickID.substring(0,5);
    $('#'+nweID).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set active timelines on click event.

First add active class pill and info on click.

```
$('.timeline-element').click(function () {

    // Removes old active elements for second click
    $('.timeline-element.active,.timeline-info.active').removeClass('active');

    var hoverID = $(this).attr("id");
    var newID = hoverID.replace('year-', '');

    // Set active
    $('#' + newID).addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Then go to css and write new style for active class.

```
.timeline-info.active {
    display:block !important;
}
.timeline-element.active{
    background-color: #051A5B;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s4yvbqzL/3/ there is a working demo.

**Edit  for close activated elements**

```
$('.timeline-element').click(function () {

        var deActive = $(this).hasClass('active');

        // Removes old active elements for second click
        $('.timeline-element.active,.timeline-info.active').removeClass('active');

        // If clicked element is not active, activate it.
        if(deActive == false) {
            var hoverID = $(this).attr("id");
            var newID = hoverID.replace('year-', '');

            // Set active
            $('#' + newID).addClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/s4yvbqzL/4/

Comment: This only works partially, I wanted it to be so that when you click on the button again, the info will be hidden again, where this will show info until the page is refreshed

Comment: You can play with it after detect what's active. For example, I checked clicked timeline element is active before open it. So, in this way if timeline element activated just removes active class. I hope its helps and you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the .off() method of jQuery to unbind the listener to the mouseenter and mouseleave events you added with the .on() method and add them again if you click a button for the second time.